# How to load wordpress child theme css after parent theme css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

In my wordpress child theme css file loaded before main theme css.
My child theme css functions.php file is given below

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../enfold-child/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

I want to load child theme css after parent theme css.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add the priority. Here 99 is high, so it will likely be last but some plugins may add css at a higher priority, though it's rare.

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles(){
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/../enfold-child/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there any alternative solution without setting highest priority?

Comment: Locate the parent theme's priority, dequeue it and then add it back in with no priority and then you call your style sheet

Comment: Thanks for your nice response

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes),
set the parent style as a dependency of the child style, and load it in your functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // You'll find this somewhere in the parent theme in a wp_enqueue_style('parent-style').
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

**Beware though, that some themes use more than one stylesheet.** 
If that occurs, you can add any and all of them to the function like this:

```
    $parent_style = 'parent-style';
    $parent_style2 = 'other-parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style2, get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style, $parent_style2 ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

for CHILD THEME **get_stylesheet_directory_uri()**

for PARENT THEME  **get_template_directory_uri()**

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 

wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css' );


wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```